# How to use url with parameter in blade Laravel

Tags: laravel, url, routes, stylesheet, laravel-blade

I try to use different stylesheets in my `master.blade.php` for different pages. When I use simple routes it works.

```php
@if ( Request::path() == 'videos/alpes')
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('/css/style-vid.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all">
@elseif (Request::path() == 'texts')
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('/css/style-lir.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all">
@else
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('/css/style-all-together.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all">
```

But I can't find the way to use in `@if` statement a route with parameters i.e.

```
Route::get('/videos/{video}', 'VideoController@show');
```

I try to do it for all videos, not just for one of them (alpes). Is  there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try use [action helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-action):

> The action function generates a URL for the given controller action. You do not need to pass the full namespace to the controller. Instead, pass the controller class name relative to the  `App\Http\Controllers` namespace:
>
> `$url = action('HomeController@getIndex');`
>
> If the method accepts route parameters, you may pass them as the second argument to the method:
>
> `$url = action('UserController@profile', ['id' => 1]);`

In your variant:

```
@if(Request::url() == action('VideoController@show', ['video' => $video]))
    //some code
@endif
```

You can change your code `Request::path() == 'videos/alpes'` to `Request::is('video/alpes')`